# How to reboot server using Ansible if stdout result equal failed?

Tags: ansible, devops

I write tasks for jboss, but i don't know how to restart server if stdout result equal failed.

My task:

```
- name: Server
  become: true
  check_deployments: 
    server: 111.111.111.111:8888
    command: /deployment=*:read-attribute(name=status)
    cli_path: /testusers/wildfly/bin
    user: admin
    password: admin
  register: command

- name: wf_debug  
  debug:
    msg: "{{ command.stdout_lines}}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [check_wf_status : wf_debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [111.111.111.111] => {
    "msg": [
        "{",
        "    \"outcome\" => \"success\",",
        "    \"result\" => [",
        "        {",
        "            \"address\" => [(\"deployment\" => \"test-module1\")],",
        "            \"outcome\" => \"success\",",
        "            \"result\" => \"OK\"",
        "        },",
        "        {",
        "            \"address\" => [(\"deployment\" => \"test-module2\")],",
        "            \"outcome\" => \"success\",",
        "            \"result\" => \"FAILED\"",
        "        },",
        "    ]",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

How to reboot server using Ansible if result = FAILED ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to reboot server using Ansible if result = FAILED ?

This should work, as [to the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html):

```yaml
- name: Unconditionally reboot the machine with all defaults, when the check_deployments task has failed
  reboot:
  when: "'FAILED' in command.stdout_lines"
```

Please note, that you're registering "command". This is also an ansible module, which could cause confusion. It's better to register it with another name, e.g. `register: check_deploy`.

Comment: When i play my playbook with -vvv : "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False". How to resolve it?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Worked for me: when: "'FAILED' in command.stdout" without lines